# Can the entropy of a part of a closed system become less than the initial entropy of the entire system?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I am reading Sir Roger Penrose's book "What came before the Big Bang?". Here, I came across a chapter where he talks about how sunlight provides us energy in low entropy and how through various processes this energy is transformed into higher entropy values through photosynthesis etc.
Now, my question is can photosynthesis generate carbohydrates which have lower entropy than the incident light energy, even though the byproducts of the reaction can contribute to overall increase in energy?
For example, plants produce food and animals consume them and higher level animals consume these animals. Can the entropy of the animals which consume plants be less than the entropy of the plants themselves?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question you are trying to ask is yes, but I will need to do a bit of explanation.

First, be aware the entropy is like mass or volume, in the sense that if you have two copies of something, the two copies will have twice as much entropy as the single object, exactly the same way they have twice the mass or volume. Because of this, you should be careful when you are trying to identify how ordered something is with what its entropy is. A complex system like a human may still have more entropy than a small rock because the human is large and the rock is small. That is just a caveat I thought you should know about.

The main idea of your question though is if a low entropy system can get to an even lower entropy by interacting with a higher entropy system. The answer is yes.

I think your confusion is that you are thinking of entropy like temperature, and you are thinking that if the low entropy system eats the high entropy system, then they will equilibrate and the final entropy of the low entropy system must be higher.

This is not how entropy works though. There is no law that says that if two systems are in contact, there entropies must equilibrate. The law is that if two systems interact, their total entropy must not decrease. Thus the low entropy system is allowed to make its entropy even lower provided that it makes the high entropy system's entropy even higher (by an amount equal to the low entropy system's decrease, or more).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I was unknowingly considering entropy to be similar to temperature instead of treating it like mass, volume etc. Now, I have some clarity in what I was thinking. So, I would like to rephrase my question as follows: If there is plant source of energy 100Cal and an animal source of energy 100Cal for a human being, where the animal derived that energy from a similar plant source, can we say for sure that the animal source of energy has greater entropy than the plant one? Or is it possible that the animal source can have lesser entropy than the plant source?